# Online MYSQL editor as an Excel-like spreadsheet

Tags: mysql

I have a database that it will be updated by users that has absolutely no knowledge in programming. It needs to be something as simple as possible.

I wanted an online front-end MySQL editor that it looks like a spreadsheet in Excel. Just like [this JavaScript plugin](http://handsontable.com/), but this one doesn't connect with MySQL.

Comment: @DrewPierce That depends on who are those users, and whether they just need to store data in a vague form but with shared access. Once they'll be past that, he'll have to devise a web form instead of raw DB access.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is way too advanced. MS Excel needs configuration. I need something to run on the browser in every computer without any configuration. And this one from CodeCanyon doesn't work here ("Error: the verification key is out of date")

Comment: you bought the codecanyon that quickly ?

Comment: Saw their demo. Wont buy something that even the demo doesn't work.

Comment: i can put it on aws ec2 you can check it out. it has 2500 sales by the guy and he updates it !